# finding minumum of list of tuples in HASKELL

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I've tried to find  tuples(one or more) which have a minumum distance((x1,x2) and (y1,y2) distance= abs(y2-y1) +abs(x2-x1)  with a specific point. For example :

> List would be [(1,2),(3,4),(5,4),(5,6),(9,12)  ]
>
> and the specific point is (xpos,ypos)=(4,4).

Then my function should return [(3,4),(5,4)].I've tried to implement this but i have a kind of problem and i think it is related to base case. Is there anyone who can help me ?

```
disSolver xpos ypos coor = abs (xpos - (fst coor)) +abs(ypos-(snd coor))



closestTuple _ _ [] =[]
closestTuple xpos ypos (x:y:xs) = if (disSolver xpos ypos x)<= (disSolver xpos ypos y)
then [x] ++ closestTuple xpos ypos (xs)
else closestTuple xpos ypos (y:xs)
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the case when the list to find the nearest points from contains exactly 1 element. It also seems there is a bug in logic of your `closestTuple` implementation.

Here is how I would write the function:

```
distSolver :: Num a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
distSolver (px, py) (x, y) = (abs (x - px)) + (abs (y - py))

closestTuple :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
closestTuple _ [] = []
closestTuple pos (x:xs) = mins (distSolver pos x) [x] pos xs

mins _ mxs _ [] = mxs
mins minDist mxs pos (x:xs)
    | dist < minDist  = mins dist [x] pos xs
    | dist == minDist = mins dist (x:mxs) pos xs
    | otherwise       = mins minDist mxs pos xs
  where dist = distSolver pos x
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i realized my fault but i've already posted it,so i couldnt chance :(, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You've factored out `disSolver` into its own function, that's good. You can go further and also abstract out the algorithm for “finding the minimums by some specified metric”. `closestTuple` is then just the composition of the two. (Except I'm using leventov's `distSolver` instead of your `disSolver`, because the types fit together better.)

I've chosen to demonstrate `minimaBy` using a pipeline of functions instead of explicit pattern matching and recursion, because I happen to think it's clearer and less error-prone in this case.

Also note that the type I've given `minimaBy` means that if it compiles, it is automatically free of certain bugs. We can't accidentally sort by the `c` type (corresponding to `(a, a)` in `closestTuple`'s signature) because only `b` is declared to implement `Ord`.

(Having said that, I've not compiled or otherwise tested this code, it's only guaranteed to work flawlessly in my head :-) )

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy, sortBy)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe, listToMaybe)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

minimaBy :: Ord b => (c -> b) -> [c] -> [c]
minimaBy f = map fst
           . fromMaybe []
           . listToMaybe
           . groupBy ((==) `on` snd)
           . sortBy (comparing snd)
           . map (id &&& f)

closestTuple :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a, a) -> [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
closestTuple = minimaBy . distSolver
```

Links to documentation:

- Control.Arrow --- [`&&&`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html#v%3a-38--38--38-)

  - ignore the typeclass for now
  - pretend that `(&&&) :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c') -> (b -> (c, c'))`
- Data.Function --- [`on`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Function.html#v%3aon)
- Data.List --- [`groupBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3agroupBy), [`sortBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3asortBy)
- Data.Maybe --- [`fromMaybe`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromMaybe), [`listToMaybe`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html#v%3alistToMaybe)
- Data.Ord --- [`comparing`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html#v%3acomparing)

Comment: Nice. Though `fromMaybe[] . listToMaybe` is a bit roundabout-ish. `take 1` may be less explicit but is IMO still clearer, being so simple.

Comment: `groupBy snd` doesn't typecheck. I think it should be ``groupBy ((==) `on` snd)``

Comment: @leftaroundabout `fromMaybe [] . listToMaybe :: [[a]] -> [a]` but `take 1 :: [a] -> [a]`. I would use [`headMay` from safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/0.3.3/doc/html/Safe.html#v:headMay) instead of `listToMaybe`, to make the intent clearer, but it's not in the Haskell Platform. Is there anything more idiomatic?

Comment: @dave4420: right, `concat . take 1` was what I meant. Which admittedly isn't that nice anymore.

Comment: It strikes me that I accidentally use (something isomorphic to) [the environment comonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/3.0.1/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Env.html) in `minimaBy`.

Comment: Don't think I'm caviling, but IMO `minimaBy` would be better implemented as my `closestTuple` with mapping ("by") parameter instead of `pos`. Advantages: 1) less dependencies (no deps indeed);  2) single-pass (better perf). Disadvantages: 1) 2 functions instead of 1 (minor thing); 2) probably a bit less readable, however your point-free tower is also not ideal.

Comment: @leventov Maybe. But note that all the modules I use are in the base package that comes with GHC: I wouldn't count them as separate dependencies.